# How to save images into playerprefs and display them to another scene?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in Unity.  And so far of what I read, playerprefs could store image in a byte form. Still, I'm having trouble in this one. Because, I'm having an error in converting texture2d to bytes. In which, I use this code

```
Texture tex = Resources.Load("Sprites/white_black") as Texture2D;
byte[] texbyte = tex.EncodeToPNG();
// ^ this line always result as NullReferenceException on my console.
```

I have two scenes: Scene1 is images that were going to save to playerprefs which is an example below:
[image]

While in Scene 2, all the images that were saved in playerprefs will be show using a button like in below pic:
[image]

Also, if you could recommend me other solution I'll search on it. Thank you.

Comment: check if the texture is readable. Texture2d.isReadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not save images in PlayerPrefs but you could just save the name of the sprite to PlayerPrefs, and then load it in another scene from resources, like so: `Resources.Load(spriteName);`